# Converting Markdown to PowerPoint presentations

Tags: presentations, markdown

I really like to use Markdown markup for quickly drafting my presentations with a text editor.

When the presentation is in a good shape, I have to finalize it as a PowerPoint file.

Currently I create a new PowerPoint presentation and cut & paste to copy content from my text editor. Is there a tool that converts Markdown files (or reStructuredText) to PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on iOS, [makeSlides](http://toketaware.com/makeslides) claims to do just that though I haven't tried it (I don't use iOS).